# Containerizing Django application connected to sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, docker

Guidance required to containerize an existing django application which is connected to an existing docker image of sql server.

I am not understanding how to write a docker-compose file which will have the database entries which will connect to an existing sql server database image.

The sql_server image is running on port 1433 and access URL is localhost:1433. I can connect to the server and app works fine when I run from a virtual environment.

Here's the Dockerfile...

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Project Files / Settings
RUN mkdir /sch
WORKDIR /sch
ADD . /sch

# Install libraries, dependencies
RUN apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc unixodbc-dev 
RUN pip3 install pyodbc
RUN pip3 install django-pyodbc-azure
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Server
EXPOSE 8003
STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]  
CMD ["/web/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8003"]
```

Here's the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003"
    container_name: sch
    volumes:
      - .:/sch
    ports:
      - "8003:8003"
```

Now, the error I am getting is...

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql_server'

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.
```

Comment: If the database is already running, you don't need to set it up on your docker-compose file. You just need to make sure that the 1433 port is exposed and listening.

Comment: "localhost" in Docker always means "this container", never the physical host or another container.  The `volumes:` you have is convenient for development but not representative of a real production setup, and strictly harder to use than non-Docker tooling like Python virtual environments.  It's not clear from what you've shown what specific problem you're encountering, though.

Comment: I have updated the original post with more details. Please take a look.